# Не получается установить библиотеку gensim

Tags: python, docker, gensim, requirements.txt

Хочу упаковать свой проект в Docker, но во время установки библиотек из файла requirements.txt происходить ошибка, а именно с библиотекой gensim.

Ошибка такая:

```
#0 27.73 Collecting gensim==4.1.0
#0 27.76   Downloading gensim-4.1.0.tar.gz (23.2 MB)
#0 36.88      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 23.2/23.2 MB 2.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#0 37.50   Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
#0 55.77   Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
#0 55.80   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
#0 55.80
#0 55.80   × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
#0 55.80   │ exit code: 1
#0 55.80   ╰─> [303 lines of output]
#0 55.80         error: subprocess-exited-with-error
#0 55.80
#0 55.80         × Building wheel for numpy (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
#0 55.80         │ exit code: 1
#0 55.80         ╰─> [262 lines of output]
#0 55.80             Running from numpy source directory.
#0 55.80             setup.py:86: DeprecationWarning:
#0 55.80
#0 55.80               `numpy.distutils` is deprecated since NumPy 1.23.0, as a result
#0 55.80               of the deprecation of `distutils` itself. It will be removed for
#0 55.80               Python >= 3.12. For older Python versions it will remain present.
#0 55.80               It is recommended to use `setuptools < 60.0` for those Python versions.
#0 55.80               For more details, see:
#0 55.80                 https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/distutils_status_migration.html
```

Файл requirements.txt:

```
flask
razdel
pymorphy2
setuptools==59.8.0
numpy==1.19.5
nltk==3.6.2
requests==2.27.1
gensim==4.1.0
tensorflow==2.6.0
```

Пробовал сначала не указывать setuptools и версии библиотек в этом файле,но все равно возникает ошибка.

Попробовал запустить установку через cmd и Windows Terminal, ошибка одна и та же.

Вот полный текст ошибки, если нужно (проблема не с pip):

```
#0 27.67 Collecting gensim==4.1.0
#0 27.70   Downloading gensim-4.1.0.tar.gz (23.2 MB)
#0 34.73      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 23.2/23.2 MB 3.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#0 35.37   Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
#0 54.23   Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
#0 54.26   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
#0 54.26
#0 54.26   × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
#0 54.26   │ exit code: 1
#0 54.26   ╰─> [303 lines of output]
#0 54.26         error: subprocess-exited-with-error
#0 54.26
#0 54.26         × Building wheel for numpy (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
#0 54.26         │ exit code: 1
#0 54.26         ╰─> [262 lines of output]
#0 54.26             Running from numpy source directory.
#0 54.26             setup.py:86: DeprecationWarning:
#0 54.26
#0 54.26               `numpy.distutils` is deprecated since NumPy 1.23.0, as a result
#0 54.26               of the deprecation of `distutils` itself. It will be removed for
#0 54.26               Python >= 3.12. For older Python versions it will remain present.
#0 54.26               It is recommended to use `setuptools < 60.0` for those Python versions.
#0 54.26               For more details, see:
#0 54.26                 https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/distutils_status_migration.html
#0 54.26
#0 54.26
#0 54.26               import numpy.distutils.command.sdist
#0 54.26             Processing numpy/random/_bounded_integers.pxd.in
#0 54.26             Processing numpy/random/_pcg64.pyx
#0 54.26             Processing numpy/random/_philox.pyx
#0 54.26             Processing numpy/random/mtrand.pyx
#0 54.26             Processing numpy/random/_generator.pyx
#0 54.26             Processing numpy/random/_common.pyx
#0 54.26             Processing numpy/random/_mt19937.pyx
#0 54.26             Processing numpy/random/_sfc64.pyx
#0 54.26             Processing numpy/random/_bounded_integers.pyx.in
#0 54.26             Processing numpy/random/bit_generator.pyx
#0 54.26             Cythonizing sources
#0 54.26             INFO: blas_opt_info:
#0 54.26             INFO: blas_armpl_info:
#0 54.26             INFO: customize UnixCCompiler
#0 54.26             INFO:   libraries armpl_lp64_mp not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
#0 54.26             INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
#0 54.26             INFO:
#0 54.26             INFO: blas_mkl_info:
#0 54.26             INFO:   libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
#0 54.26             INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
#0 54.26             INFO:
#0 54.26             INFO: blis_info:
#0 54.26             INFO:   libraries blis not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
#0 54.26             INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
#0 54.26             INFO:
#0 54.26             INFO: openblas_info:
#0 54.26             INFO:   libraries openblas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
#0 54.26             INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
#0 54.26             INFO:
#0 54.26             INFO: accelerate_info:
#0 54.26             INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
#0 54.26             INFO:
#0 54.26             INFO: atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
#0 54.26             INFO: Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
#0 54.26             INFO:   libraries tatlas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
#0 54.26             INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
#0 54.26             INFO:
#0 54.26             INFO: atlas_3_10_blas_info:
#0 54.26             INFO:   libraries satlas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
#0 54.26             INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
#0 54.26             INFO:
#0 54.26             INFO: atlas_blas_threads_info:
#0 54.26             INFO: Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
#0 54.26             INFO:   libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
#0 54.26             INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
#0 54.26             INFO:
#0 54.26             INFO: atlas_blas_info:
#0 54.26             INFO:   libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
#0 54.26             INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
#0 54.26             INFO:
#0 54.26             /tmp/pip-wheel-j1x1h6lq/numpy_f9ce2c8ec08c493da938e81986307838/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:2077: UserWarning:
#0 54.26                 Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.
#0 54.26                 Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.
#0 54.26                 A better performance should be easily gained by switching
#0 54.26                 Blas library.
#0 54.26               if self._calc_info(blas):
#0 54.26             INFO: blas_info:
#0 54.26             INFO:   libraries blas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
#0 54.26             INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
#0 54.26             INFO:
#0 54.26             /tmp/pip-wheel-j1x1h6lq/numpy_f9ce2c8ec08c493da938e81986307838/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:2077: UserWarning:
#0 54.26                 Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
#0 54.26                 Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
#0 54.26                 numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
#0 54.26                 the BLAS environment variable.
#0 54.26               if self._calc_info(blas):
#0 54.26             INFO: blas_src_info:
#0 54.26             INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
#0 54.26             INFO:
#0 54.26             /tmp/pip-wheel-j1x1h6lq/numpy_f9ce2c8ec08c493da938e81986307838/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:2077: UserWarning:
#0 54.26                 Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
#0 54.26                 Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
#0 54.26                 numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
#0 54.26                 the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
#0 54.26               if self._calc_info(blas):
#0 54.26             INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
#0 54.26             INFO:
#0 54.26             non-existing path in 'numpy/distutils': 'site.cfg'
#0 54.26             INFO: lapack_opt_info:
#0 54.26             INFO: lapack_armpl_info:
#0 54.26             INFO:   libraries armpl_lp64_mp not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
#0 54.26             INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
#0 54.26             INFO:
#0 54.26             INFO: lapack_mkl_info:
#0 54.26             INFO:   libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
#0 54.26             INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
#0 54.26             INFO:
#0 54.26             INFO: openblas_lapack_info:
#0 54.26             INFO:   libraries openblas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
#0 54.26             INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
#0 54.26             INFO:
#0 54.26             INFO: openblas_clapack_info:
#0 54.26             INFO:   libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
#0 54.26             INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
#0 54.26             INFO:
#0 54.26             INFO: flame_info:
#0 54.26             INFO:   libraries flame not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
#0 54.26             INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
#0 54.26             INFO:
#0 54.26             INFO: atlas_3_10_threads_info:
#0 54.26             INFO: Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
#0 54.26             INFO:   libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/local/lib
#0 54.26             INFO:   libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib
#0 54.26             INFO:   libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib/
#0 54.26             INFO: <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
#0 54.26             INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
#0 54.26             INFO:
#0 54.26             INFO: atlas_3_10_info:
#0 54.26             INFO:   libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/local/lib
#0 54.26             INFO:   libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib
#0 54.26             INFO:   libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib/
#0 54.26             INFO: <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
#0 54.26             INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
#0 54.26             INFO:
#0 54.26             INFO: atlas_threads_info:
#0 54.26             INFO: Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
#0 54.26             INFO:   libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
#0 54.26             INFO:   libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
#0 54.26             INFO:   libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib/
#0 54.26             INFO: <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
#0 54.26             INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
#0 54.26             INFO:
#0 54.26             INFO: atlas_info:
#0 54.26             INFO:   libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
#0 54.26             INFO:   libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
#0 54.26             INFO:   libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib/
#0 54.26             INFO: <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
#0 54.26             INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
#0 54.26             INFO:
#0 54.26             INFO: lapack_info:
#0 54.26             INFO:   libraries lapack not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
#0 54.26             INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
#0 54.26             INFO:
#0 54.26             /tmp/pip-wheel-j1x1h6lq/numpy_f9ce2c8ec08c493da938e81986307838/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1902: UserWarning:
#0 54.26                 Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
#0 54.26                 Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
#0 54.26                 numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
#0 54.26                 the LAPACK environment variable.
#0 54.26               return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
#0 54.26             INFO: lapack_src_info:
#0 54.26             INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
#0 54.26             INFO:
#0 54.26             /tmp/pip-wheel-j1x1h6lq/numpy_f9ce2c8ec08c493da938e81986307838/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1902: UserWarning:
#0 54.26                 Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
#0 54.26                 Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
#0 54.26                 numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
#0 54.26                 the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
#0 54.26               return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
#0 54.26             INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
#0 54.26             INFO:
#0 54.26             INFO: numpy_linalg_lapack_lite:
#0 54.26             INFO:   FOUND:
#0 54.26             INFO:     language = c
#0 54.26             INFO:     define_macros = [('HAVE_BLAS_ILP64', None), ('BLAS_SYMBOL_SUFFIX', '64_')]
#0 54.26             INFO:
#0 54.26             Warning: attempted relative import with no known parent package
#0 54.26             /usr/local/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
#0 54.26               warnings.warn(msg)
#0 54.26             running bdist_wheel
#0 54.26             running build
#0 54.26             running config_cc
#0 54.26             INFO: unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
#0 54.26             running config_fc
#0 54.26             INFO: unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
#0 54.26             running build_src
#0 54.26             INFO: build_src
#0 54.26             INFO: building py_modules sources
#0 54.26             creating build
#0 54.26             creating build/src.linux-x86_64-3.9
#0 54.26             creating build/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy
#0 54.26             creating build/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/distutils
#0 54.26             INFO: building library "npymath" sources
#0 54.26             WARN: Could not locate executable armflang
#0 54.26             WARN: Could not locate executable gfortran
#0 54.26             WARN: Could not locate executable f95
#0 54.26             WARN: Could not locate executable ifort
#0 54.26             WARN: Could not locate executable ifc
#0 54.26             WARN: Could not locate executable lf95
#0 54.26             WARN: Could not locate executable pgfortran
#0 54.26             WARN: Could not locate executable nvfortran
#0 54.26             WARN: Could not locate executable f90
#0 54.26             WARN: Could not locate executable f77
#0 54.26             WARN: Could not locate executable fort
#0 54.26             WARN: Could not locate executable efort
#0 54.26             WARN: Could not locate executable efc
#0 54.26             WARN: Could not locate executable g77
#0 54.26             WARN: Could not locate executable g95
#0 54.26             WARN: Could not locate executable pathf95
#0 54.26             WARN: Could not locate executable nagfor
#0 54.26             WARN: Could not locate executable frt
#0 54.26             WARN: don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'posix'
#0 54.26
#0 54.26
#0 54.26             [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'g++'
#0 54.26
#0 54.26
#0 54.26             Traceback (most recent call last):
#0 54.26               File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
#0 54.26                 main()
#0 54.26               File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 345, in main
#0 54.26                 json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
#0 54.26               File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 261, in build_wheel
#0 54.26                 return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
#0 54.26               File "/tmp/pip-build-env-kjuvogoo/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 230, in build_wheel
#0 54.26                 return self._build_with_temp_dir(['bdist_wheel'], '.whl',
#0 54.26               File "/tmp/pip-build-env-kjuvogoo/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 215, in _build_with_temp_dir
#0 54.26                 self.run_setup()
#0 54.26               File "/tmp/pip-build-env-kjuvogoo/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 267, in run_setup
#0 54.26                 super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
#0 54.26               File "/tmp/pip-build-env-kjuvogoo/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 158, in run_setup
#0 54.26                 exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
#0 54.26               File "setup.py", line 493, in <module>
#0 54.26                 setup_package()
#0 54.26               File "setup.py", line 485, in setup_package
#0 54.26                 setup(**metadata)
#0 54.26               File "/tmp/pip-wheel-j1x1h6lq/numpy_f9ce2c8ec08c493da938e81986307838/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 169, in setup
#0 54.26                 return old_setup(**new_attr)
#0 54.26               File "/tmp/pip-build-env-kjuvogoo/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 153, in setup
#0 54.26                 return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
#0 54.26               File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
#0 54.26                 dist.run_commands()
#0 54.26               File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
#0 54.26                 self.run_command(cmd)
#0 54.26               File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
#0 54.26                 cmd_obj.run()
#0 54.26               File "/tmp/pip-build-env-kjuvogoo/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 299, in run
#0 54.26                 self.run_command('build')
#0 54.26               File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
#0 54.26                 self.distribution.run_command(command)
#0 54.26               File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
#0 54.26                 cmd_obj.run()
#0 54.26               File "/tmp/pip-wheel-j1x1h6lq/numpy_f9ce2c8ec08c493da938e81986307838/numpy/distutils/command/build.py", line 62, in run
#0 54.26                 old_build.run(self)
#0 54.26               File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
#0 54.26                 self.run_command(cmd_name)
#0 54.26               File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
#0 54.26                 self.distribution.run_command(command)
#0 54.26               File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
#0 54.26                 cmd_obj.run()
#0 54.26               File "/tmp/pip-wheel-j1x1h6lq/numpy_f9ce2c8ec08c493da938e81986307838/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 144, in run
#0 54.26                 self.build_sources()
#0 54.26               File "/tmp/pip-wheel-j1x1h6lq/numpy_f9ce2c8ec08c493da938e81986307838/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 155, in build_sources
#0 54.26                 self.build_library_sources(*libname_info)
#0 54.26               File "/tmp/pip-wheel-j1x1h6lq/numpy_f9ce2c8ec08c493da938e81986307838/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 288, in build_library_sources
#0 54.26                 sources = self.generate_sources(sources, (lib_name, build_info))
#0 54.26               File "/tmp/pip-wheel-j1x1h6lq/numpy_f9ce2c8ec08c493da938e81986307838/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 378, in generate_sources
#0 54.26                 source = func(extension, build_dir)
#0 54.26               File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 758, in get_mathlib_info
#0 54.26                 raise RuntimeError(
#0 54.26             RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C++ program. note: A compiler with support for C++11 language features is required.
#0 54.26             [end of output]
#0 54.26
#0 54.26         note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
#0 54.26         ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
#0 54.26       ERROR: Failed to build one or more wheels
#0 54.26       Traceback (most recent call last):
#0 54.26         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/installer.py", line 75, in fetch_build_egg
#0 54.26           subprocess.check_call(cmd)
#0 54.26         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 373, in check_call
#0 54.26           raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
#0 54.26       subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/local/bin/python', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', '/tmp/tmph7qoi3a9', '--quiet', 'numpy>=1.17.0']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
#0 54.26
#0 54.26       The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
#0 54.26
#0 54.26       Traceback (most recent call last):
#0 54.26         File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
#0 54.26         File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
#0 54.26         File "/tmp/pip-install-w3no3pn_/gensim_1ea3dae9a41449ef8abc5ac7408f64f4/setup.py", line 339, in <module>
#0 54.26           setup(
#0 54.26         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 152, in setup
#0 54.26           _install_setup_requires(attrs)
#0 54.26         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 147, in _install_setup_requires
#0 54.26           dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
#0 54.26         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 806, in fetch_build_eggs
#0 54.26           resolved_dists = pkg_resources.working_set.resolve(
#0 54.26         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 766, in resolve
#0 54.26           dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(
#0 54.26         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1051, in best_match
#0 54.26           return self.obtain(req, installer)
#0 54.26         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1063, in obtain
#0 54.26           return installer(requirement)
#0 54.26         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 877, in fetch_build_egg
#0 54.26           return fetch_build_egg(self, req)
#0 54.26         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/installer.py", line 77, in fetch_build_egg
#0 54.26           raise DistutilsError(str(e)) from e
#0 54.26       distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Command '['/usr/local/bin/python', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', '/tmp/tmph7qoi3a9', '--quiet', 'numpy>=1.17.0']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
#0 54.26       [end of output]
#0 54.26
#0 54.26   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
#0 54.26 error: metadata-generation-failed
#0 54.26
#0 54.26 × Encountered error while generating package metadata.
#0 54.26 ╰─> See above for output.
#0 54.26
#0 54.26 note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
#0 54.26 hint: See above for details.
#0 54.26 WARNING: You are using pip version 22.0.4; however, version 22.2 is available.
#0 54.26 You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: Основная ошибка вот эта я так понимаю: "RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C++ program. note: A compiler with support for C++11 language features is required." Требуется компилятор C++, с поддержкой фич C++ версии 11. Инсталлятор перебрал все варианты как скомпилировать исходники, не нашёл никаких вариантов, дошёл до C++ и обломался, не найдя и его даже.

Comment: @CrazyElf Как можно решить проблему?

Comment: Поставить требуемый компилятор в систему, видимо.

Comment: @CrazyElf  мне его на свою систему (Windows) надо ставить или прямо в Docker?

Comment: Туда, где ошибка выходит. Видимо, в докер, ведь это там библиотеки ставиться пытаются. И пути там явно не от винды.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помогло следующее:

Нужно было вставить строчку в Dockerfile:

```
RUN pip install setuptools==59.8.0 && pip install numpy==1.19.2
```

перед строчкой:

```
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: А, получается порядок установки важен. Вот тут ещё есть рецепты, как пакеты в указанном порядке по одному ставить https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394356/how-to-specify-install-order-for-python-pip Я думал этот вопрос как-то решён давно во всяких докерах, а всё какая-то кустарщина в итоге использутеся.

Comment: А если просто в requirements.txt поставить `setuptools==59.8.0` и 
`numpy==1.19.5` в начало? Либо только установку setuptools вынести наружу

Comment: @insolor Ну вот судя по той ссылке порядок в `requirements` менять без толку. Хотя странно, я думал за столько лет что-то придумали на эту тему.

Comment: @CrazyElf даже если порядок строк в reqirements.txt ни на что не влияет, скорее всего в данном случае достаточно именно setuptools предварительно обновить, потом уже устанавливать все из requirements.txt, в том числе numpy

Comment: @insolor Вполне возможно. Хотя я помню, что `numpy` в целом довольно капризный и его установка часто без бубна не обходится. Не удивлюсь, если его таки надо отдельно от всего остального ставить.